# Pivotal/tap failed on brew

Tags: java, homebrew

I am trying to tap pivotal with the following command

**brew tap pivotal/tap**

But getting the following error.

```
Error: Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/pivotal/homebrew-tap/trilogy.rb
trilogy: Calling depends_on :java is disabled! Use "depends_on "openjdk@11", "depends_on "openjdk@8" or "depends_on "openjdk" instead.
Please report this issue to the pivotal/tap tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it:
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/pivotal/homebrew-tap/trilogy.rb:9
```

In trilogy.rb, it does use depends_on :java

I try to set the JAVA_HOME but seems it does not work. Any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

While you are waiting for [this fix PR](https://github.com/pivotal-legacy/homebrew-tap/pull/177) to be merged to the master.

You can try out this solution for your own use:

- `brew tap pivotal/tap` (this does not work, see `[update]` below)
- `brew edit trilogy`
- replace `depends_on :java` with `depends_on "openjdk"` (basically that patch PR)
- save the change
- `brew install trilogy`

My installation result

```
$ trilogy --version
                                                  ver. 0.3.2
                    ********  ********
                    ******  **  ******
                    ****   ****   ****
                    **    ******    **
                    *    ********    *
                        **********
                      *************

      _______ _____  _____ __     ____   _______     __
     |__   __|  __ \|_   _| |    / __ \ / ____\ \   / /
        | |  | |__) | | | | |   | |  | | |  __ \ \_/ /
        | |  |  _  /  | | | |   | |  | | | |_ | \   /
        | |  | | \ \ _| |_| |___| |__| | |__| |  | |
        |_|  |_|  \_\_____|______\____/ \_____|  |_|

[==   Database Logic Testing Framework by Pivotal Labs   ==]

Usage: trilogy [<filePath>|--project=<path to trilogy test project>] --db_url=<jdbc url> --db_user=<db user name> --db_password=<db user password>
The db_url, db_user and db_password can be replaced by setting environment variables with the same name in upper case
Run `trilogy --help` to display this help message
```

#### [update]

If you run into `brew tap pivotal/tap` issue, please do this (which is a manual `brew tap xx`).

- `mkdir -p /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/pivotal/homebrew-tap`
- `cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/pivotal/homebrew-tap`
- `git clone https://github.com/pivotal-legacy/homebrew-tap .`

Answer (score 1):

As the error message already says there is an issue in one of pivotals formula.
You can't do much except what the error already tells you:

> Please report this issue to the pivotal/tap tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it:
> /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/pivotal/homebrew-tap/trilogy.rb:9

EDIT:
Seems like other users were faster. There is already a issue on there github repo:
https://github.com/pivotal-legacy/homebrew-tap/issues/176

Comment: is there an alternative to set java ? I am new to it.

Comment: As said i don't think you can do anything. This formulas are like recipes and brew does whatever is written in this recipe. (Except if it can't do what is written in the recipe like in this case)

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot has relocated to `spring-io/tap`.
To upgrade Spring Boot, retap it with:

```
brew uninstall springboot
brew untap pivotal/tap
brew tap spring-io/tap
brew install spring-boot
```